# Toggle or disable/re-enable an AngularJS watch

Tags: angularjs, toggle, listener, watch

I need to be able to ignore specific watches while performing specific tasks. Here is the scenario.

---

I have a couple watchers on fields which are being used to calculate a "totals" field.

All of these fields can be manually modified, which will trigger the watches which calculate the "totals" field.

The fields can also be loaded from a saved state, which also triggers the watches which calculate the "totals" field.

The "totals" field can also be manually overridden, saved, and loaded.

The problem occurs when a manually overridden "totals" field is loaded with the other fields. The watches which recalculate the "totals" are triggered, and overwrite the manually overridden "totals".

I need to be able to ignore watches while the load is occurring. Is there any way to to this?

I know a watcher can be disabled using the de-registration function that is passed back when you create a watch, but when you re-create the watcher is still knows that the data it was watching has changed.

Note: This is an oversimplified description of the business logic surrounding the issue. Not being able to disable a watch would require a significant amount of work.

Here is a fiddle showing the problem: jsfiddle.net/vGWZy/1/

Comment: Is there any reason you are using watches in particular? By the sounds of it, `$scope` should be able to take care of all of this. Maybe creating a fiddle will help.

Comment: This is a very large piece of business logic, and there are many ways for the data to change. Not using watches would be a nightmare. I will see if I can put together a simple fiddle to show the issue. Was hoping someone would have a definitive answer as to if this was at least possple.

Comment: I think a simple example if possible would really help here.

Comment: Added a fiddle to demonstrate the issue. jsfiddle.net/vGWZy/1/

Comment: Sorry I initially posted the wrong fiddle link. Its now been updated.

Comment: The fiddle seems to all work fine. What are the steps using the fiddle to arrive at the issue (sorry I still don't fully understand the problem). Also have you considered doing something like this in the view: `SaveTotal: {{saved.value1 * saved.value2}}`?

Comment: Type 3 into the first box, 3 into the second box. The totals should be 9. Then override the totals box by typing 100 into it. Save the result, load it again, and you loosed the total of 100 and get 9 back as the calculation is triggered. 
I know this sounds like ridiculous business logic, but business logic doesn't always take logic into account...

Comment: Something like this maintains the saved value of 100. http://jsfiddle.net/869qz/

Answer (score 4):

Your can store watcher's callbacks and disabler in special service, and use binding and unbinding of them with service method's

Example with your code
http://jsfiddle.net/snicksnk/66osj8zm/

```
//Service for working with watcher's binding
var watchService = {
    watchers: {},
    create: function(name, callback){

        watchService.watchers[name] = 
        {
            'callback': callback,
            'disableCallback': null
        };
    },
    enable: function($scope, name){
        if (typeof watchService.watchers[name]['callback'] !== 'function'){
            return;
        }
        watchService.disable(name);
        var watcher = watchService.watchers[name]['callback'];
        watchService.watchers[name]['disableCallback'] = $scope.$watch(name, watcher, true);


    },
    disable: function(name){
        if (typeof watchService.watchers[name]['disableCallback'] !== 'function'){
            return;
        }
        watchService.watchers[name]['disableCallback']();
    }
};

//Creating of watcher's callbacks, instead of using $scope.$watch directly
watchService.create('item.value1',  function() {
    $scope.item.total = $scope.item.value1 * $scope.item.value2;
});


watchService.create('item.value2',  function() {
    $scope.item.total = $scope.item.value1 * $scope.item.value2;
});



//Wathcers enabler
$scope.enableWatchers = function(){
    watchService.enable($scope, 'item.value1');
    watchService.enable($scope, 'item.value2');
};

//Wathcers disable
$scope.disableWatchers = function(){
    watchService.disable('item.value1');
    watchService.disable('item.value2');
};
```

Answer (score 3):

When you invoke the $watch() method, to create a binding, Angular JS returns a "de-registration" function. This function can then be used to unbind your $watch() listener - all you have to do is invoke this returned function and your $watch() listener will be removed.

```js
var leaveWatcher = function() {
  $scope.$watch('selectedStatus', function(newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue[0] === "*") {
      .......
      leaveWatcher(); //Disable
    }
  });
};

leaveWatcher(); //Enable
```

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2480-unbinding-watch-listeners-in-angularjs.htm

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try using [`ng-change`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angChange) to achieve the desired result.

Here is an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/pTZ91qHmZYUlMnrdwrZF?p=preview) that uses `ng-change` to call a function to calculate the total value.

#### View

```
<html ng-app>

  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.9" data-semver="1.2.9" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="ExampleCtrl">
     <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>

    <label>Value 1:</label><input type="number" ng-model="value1" ng-change="updateTotal()"><br />
    <label>Value 2:</label><input type="number" ng-model="value2" ng-change="updateTotal()"><br />
    <label>Value 3:</label><input type="number" ng-model="value3" ng-change="updateTotal()"><br />

    <label>Total:</label><input type="number" ng-model="total" placeholder="Total"><br />
  </body>

</html>
```

#### Controller

```
function ExampleCtrl($scope){
    $scope.value1 = 0;
    $scope.value2 = 0;
    $scope.value3 = 0;
    $scope.total = 0

    $scope.updateTotal = function(){
       $scope.total = $scope.value1 + $scope.value2 + $scope.value3;
   };
}
```

This is somewhat of a trivial example but perhaps you could adjust it to suit your needs.

Comment: I don't believe ng-change would work as the values can change without any user input. I believe ng-change is only activated if the user makes an update?

Comment: In what cases might it change?

Comment: Templates can be loaded to pre-populate fields, saved state can be loaded, the user can type into the boxes, and typing into one box can trigger updates on another box.